# Modifying firewall rules with pfctl on NetBSD 4

Tags: networking, firewall, bsd, pf, netbsd

I'm wanting to modify some firewall/NAT rules on a device (Apple Airport) running NetBSD 4.0. I'm not that familiar with BSD and pf, so want to check the right approach. I can change the pf.conf file (using sed) to the required configuration, then load using `pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf`, but am wondering if this clears out the old rules first?

Alternately, what would be the best approach to doing this directly via the command line (i.e. removing old the `rdr pass` and `nat` rules, and adding new ones?)

(for context, the aim here is to be able to change NAT rules on an Apple Airport Extreme without having to restart the device, which brings the whole network down for a minute or so; I've successfully gained [ssh access](https://github.com/samuelthomas2774/airport/wiki))

Comment: `man pf.conf` in regards the "anchors" and even more.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [`/etc/rc.d/pf` on NetBSD 4.0](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/etc/rc.d/pf?rev=1.6&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&only_with_tag=netbsd-4-0-RELEASE) (or even in 9.0) the `pf_reload` function simply runs `pfctl -q -f /etc/pf.conf` so it would seem that flushing old rules is unnecessary.

To manually flush all rules and state you could use `pfctl -F all`.

In case the Airport does not have manual pages installed, you can read the manual page for [`pfctl(8)`](https://man.netbsd.org/NetBSD-4.0/pfctl.8) online.

I looked for a command to dump the currently present rules (similar to [`ipfstat(8)`](https://man.netbsd.org/NetBSD-4.0/ipfstat.8)) but could not find anything in the manuals. It would have been helpful for inspecting the state of the firewall.